# MOV_RESAVE_CORRUPTED error on submitting app preview

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

When uploading an app preview to the app store submit process, I receive an unknown error `MOV_RESAVE_CORRUPTED` which is not documented anywhere in their uploading process.
I have captured the preview using QuickTime and had to reformat it using `ffmpeg` to a 30 FPS video, using this command

`ffmpeg -r 30 -i preview1.mov -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=886:1920,setsar=1:1 preview1-edit.mp4`

The video is working fine on my local machine but upload won't work.

Frankly, the whole process is very annoying and super stressful. Hopefully I can help anyone else having this problem with this thread.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

SOLUTION: In my case the issue was the audio encoding, used Handbrake free video tool and ensured the video specs were set to:

Video Codec (FPS) to : H.264(x264) Video Framerate (FPS) to : 30 Audio Codec to : AAC (Core Audio) Audio Mixdown to : Stereo Audio Sample rate to : 44.1 Audio Bitrate to : 256

The app preview videos are working fine now!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me. Can you, please post a screenshot of the Handbreak video and audio settings you used to create a preview video? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Preset. Set name iPhone 6.5 App Preview to recognize easily.

[image: Create preset]

Select Audio Behavior. Set samplerate to 44.1, bitrate to 256. Then save it
[image: Select behavior]

Go to Audio tab. Then select Presets from right up corner.
[image: audio]

Check audio samplerate and bitrate then click Start. Then upload it.

[image: current preset]

Answer (score 0):

App Store Connect is very tough about video formats, only accepts H264 + AAC in mp4 or mov container, otherwise it just says (after 10 minutes): MOV_RESAVE_CORRUPTED. See details: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8